# Float to Int inside a nested list with string and datetime fields that can not be changed

Tags: python

I would like to change the floats in the below nested list to integers with list comprehension. Is there a way to add an if statement for the datetime.date and string field.

```
temp_list = [[datetime.date(2020, 2, 1), '111', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [datetime.date(2020, 2, 1), '112', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [datetime.date(2020, 2, 1), '113', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

```
t1  = [[int(float(n)) for n in lst] for lst in temp_list]
```

When I run above code I get
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'

Also I believe list comprehension would be the fastest for this on millions of lists is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to keep all items within a list and just cast float to int, you can use this:

```
t1  = [[int(float(n)) if isinstance(n, float) else n for n in lst] for lst in temp_list]
```

Comment: Thank you I like the if isinstance(n, float) this will help with a lot of thing.

Answer (score 2):

This will do.

```
t1 = [[int(n) if type(n) == 'float' else n for n in lst] for lst in temp_list]
```

Note: there is no need for `float(int(n))`. `int(n)` is enough

Answer (score 0):

The output of `datetime.date` is `2020-02-01`. That can't be converted to a float. What output do you expect it gives?